# Finding an integral curve (applications of differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

Find a curve whose distance of every tangent from the origin $ON$ is equal to the $x$ axis coordinate of the point of intersection between the curve and that tangent $OU$.

How to set up the graph for this kind of problems in general?

How to form an ODE?

How to choose constant of integration and the resulting graph?

**EDIT:**

Here is the sketch:

[image]

Line $OB$ is orthogonal to tangent. The condition is that $OA=OB$

Comment: What is "every tangent from the origin"? There is only one tangent *at* the origin.

Comment: Same question, do you trace tangents that pass by O (in that case, there may not be much) or do you take a tangent in a point and measure the distance between O and the straight line ? I think the latter makes sense.

Comment: @Miguel Atencia, Distance of a tangent from the origin is equal to the normal from the origin to that tangent. There could be more than one tangent of the curve.

Comment: @zwim, Tangents are not passing the origin. Instead, they are passing through the curve.

Comment: If tangent length is double or a multiple of $x,$ the the problem makes sense. Else a trivial x-axis solution results.Can you give a rough sketch?

Comment: @Narasimham distance to x-axis would be $0$.

Comment: @Narasimham, Tangent lengths are irrelevant here. Distance of a tangent from the origin is not the tangent length. It is a normal from the origin to that tangent.

Comment: A straight line parallel to $y$ axis $ x= c $ satisfies your condition because  length of all normals= $x$ coordinate = $c$.

Comment: By definition a tangent never intersects the curve. You should slightly change your question in second line.

Comment: @user_99  Or Is It may be  x  axis intercept / segment length between point of  tangent intersection with the x-axis and origin?

Comment: @Narasimham, Yes.

Comment: That means in the sketch I added for circle case, length $ON$ should equal to $OU$ ... Right?

Comment: @Narasimham, Your $OU$ should be $OR$. We have the condition that $ON$ is equal to $OR$. Don't change anything on the graph, the condition is that $ON$ is equal to $OR$.

Comment: OK, the circle clearly does not meet the question.

Comment: user_99 OB should be sketched normal to tangent and appear reasonably equal in length to OA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Let me rephrase the question, if I have understood it right.
Write the ODE that corresponds to the *family* of curves that fulfill this condition: if we consider the tangent to one such curve at a point $x_0>0$, then the (orthogonal) distance from this tangent line to the origin is precisely $x_0$.

Consider a curve $y=f(x)$ and a point $x_0$. Then, the tangent at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is $y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. We know that the distance from the origin to this line (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation) is:
$$
distance=\frac{|f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x_0|}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x_0))^2}}
$$
But the abscissa of the point of intersection of the tangent to the curve is $x_0$ itself, so the requested ODE is, dropping the subindex of $x_0$:
$$
x=\frac{|f(x)-f'(x)x|}{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}}
$$
or substituting $y=f(x)$ for clarity:
$$
x=\frac{|y-y'\,x|}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}
$$
Squaring and simplifying yields:
$$
x^2-y^2+2y y' x=0
$$
or
$$
y'=\frac{y}{2x} - \frac{x}{2y}
$$
which is a well known Bernouilli's equation with solution $C x=x^2+y^2$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dy%2F(2x)-x%2F(2y))

Comment: Solution should be $Cx=x^2+y^2,C\neq 0$. I don't know if this is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the tangent at abscissa $x$ is

$$Y-y(x)-y'(x)(X-x)=0$$ so that the distance to the origin is

$$\frac{|0-y-y'\cdot(0-x)|}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$$ and is known to equal $x$.

Squaring and rearranging,

$$y^2-2xyy'+x^2y'^2=x^2+x^2y'^2,$$

$$y^2-2xyy'=x^2,$$

$$\left(\frac{y^2}x\right)'=-1.$$

Then after integration

$$y^2=x(C-x).$$

---

Discussion:

As the distance is an absolute value, both signs in $y=\pm\sqrt{x(C-x)}$ are valid and we can leave the equation in its quadratic form.

Comment: By change $u=x-c/2$ this gives $y^2+u^2=c^2/4$ this is a circle centered in $(c/2,0)$.

Comment: Trying to reconcile the circle you had got with the kite diagram I have given above. I am  quite sure both are correct.  The the solution I have given which fits in enclosed within the circle $ y^2= x(C-x) $ It would great if a comprehensive justifiable picture is obtained.

Comment: You did a mistake in the expression of distance from the origin. Improve it by $$\frac{|0-y +xy'(x)|}{\sqrt{1+y'^2(x)}}$$ and is known to equal $x$.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: this wasn't a mistake but an ambiguiy in the notation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is not a solution, but I thought having a picture could help fixing ideas.

For every point $A,B,C,...$ on x-axis, draw a circle centerred in $O$.

Since the distance to the tangent is calculated by the perpendicular to that tangent, then it has also to be tangent to the circle. For instance $[O,g]\perp[g,GG]$ is represented on the picture in pink color.

The green curve is the one we try to compute, while the orange curve on the left is made from points where the distance to the tangent is calculated.

I started from an arbitrary point $a$ and adjusted then $b,c,...,h$ such that there is tangency with $[AA,BB]$ and so on, and that gave the green curve.

[image]

Given the answer by Yves Daoust, I added the circle in brown, and effectively it fits my construction.
Well done !

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem simply this way as commented also earlier( the curve and tangent are same):

$$ p=r \sin \psi  ,\, x= r \cos \theta ,\, \sin \psi= \cos \theta \rightarrow \theta + \psi = \pi/2 = \phi$$

[image]
which are straight lines $ x= const =p $ all parallel to $y-$axis

$$ \phi=\pi/2,3\pi/2, $$

the latter applies for straight lines to the left of the y-axis.They are directly verified above. Polar equation of curve ( = straight line)  is $ r= p \sec \theta $

As a *another ODE setup exercise* I suggest following  slightly more involved problem for you:

Find the curve whose pedal length  $p$ ( length of perpendicular dropped from origin onto tangent equals  $y$ coordinate length at point of tangency.

Solution

$$ r \sin \psi = y= r \sin \theta $$

$$ \rightarrow \psi = \theta,\, \tan \psi = \tan \theta $$

Draw differential triangle

$$ r \,d \theta = dr \, \tan \theta $$

Integrate

$$ \log \sin \theta = \log r + \log c $$

Simplify to polar form equation getting all circles equation  through origin :

$$ r = 2 R \cos (\theta - \alpha ) $$

where  $ R, \alpha $ are arbitrary constants of  rotated circles around $z$ axis with arbitrary size and orientation ( its radius and rotation of diameter from position of center on $x$ axis.)

EDIT1

It can be in fact be generalized using same method.Choose a kite shaped cyclic quadrilateral, the red line is the required curve and its own tangent line for an arbitrary inclination $ 2 \theta $ between pedal normal and x-axis drawn inclined conveniently. The pedal length $ r \sin \psi =x = p$ as shown.

[image: GeneralSetting]